# How to inject to pythonWin with startup / init commands? (python3 changed)

Tags: python-3.x, pywin32

PythonWin on python2 knew how to execute a startup file, and "inject" variables to the interpreter's local scope (to the "Immediate windows").

I used it to load startup modules and vars for testing (e.g. import x; i=2; s="string")

With python 3 it doesn't work anymore:

1. first, there's a bug in interact.py, running the old, py2 "runfile" command.
2. the new syntax, using exec() at interact.py, line:  299

   exec( open(rcfile).read() )
3. But the variables aren't injected into the interpreter's locals/globals namespace anymore.
4. right now i'm doing something very stupid:

> ```
>  from threading import Timer
>     import pywinauto
>         def fff():
>         pywinauto.keyboard.SendKeys("exec(open(x.py)){ENTER}")
>     Timer(1, fff).start()
> ```

is there another way to inject variables to PythonWin's scope?